# Optimizing a JavaScript snippet for portability and readability

Tags: javascript, jquery, portability

We have an in-house time-tracking application at the office.

We, the employees, can view an overview of our hours on a web page. This web page renders a table, with worked hours per day in table cells, which is styled as a monthly calendar. I wrote a small script which I can copy-paste in my console to get a total of hours worked too much for that month.

A relevant snippet of the HTML.

```
<td height="17" align="right" >
<font size="1">10</font>
    <b><font size="2">&nbsp;</font></b>
    <a href="/something/a" class="link">
        <b><font size="2" color=black>08:33  </font></b>
    </a>
</td>
<td height="17" align="right" ><font size="1">11</font>
    <b><font size="2">&nbsp;</font></b>
    <a href="/something/b" class="link">
        <b><font size="2" color=black>08:25  </font></b>
    </a>
</td>
```

The JavaScript snippet.

```
var elementsToParse = $(".link").find("font:not(:empty)");
var totalMinutes = 0;
$.each(elementsToParse, function(index, element) {  
    var text = $(element).text();
    var hours = parseInt(text.substr(1, 2));            
    var minutes = parseInt(text.substr(3, 2));

    var elementTotal = ((hours * 60) + minutes) - 480;

    totalMinutes += elementTotal;
});

alert('Overtime so far: ' + totalMinutes + ' minutes');
```

Any thoughts on how to make the script more compact or elegant, while maybe improving readability?

Answer (score 3):

I would make it less compact to improve readability.  Leave it up to your build process (minifier) to make things compact.  Your goal should be to make things understandable.

**Use regular expressions**

In cases like this, where you have a strict format, I *love* using regular expressions:

```
/** @const */
var TIME_FORMAT = /(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
...
"10:30".match(TIME_FORMAT) // == ["10:30", "10", "30"]
```

This makes it clear that you expect a date to consist of two digits a colon, and two more digits.  As a bonus, let everyone know it's a constant with JSDoc and common coding conventions.

**Define functions**

Short modular code is easy to read:

```
/**
 * Parses a time string and returns the hours and minutes.
 */
function parseTime(text) {
    var match = String(text).match(TIME_FORMAT);

    if (match === null) {
        throw new Error('Time "' + text + '" could not be parsed.');
    }

    return {
        hours:   Number(match[1]),
        minutes: Number(match[2])
    };
}

/**
 * Gets the total minutes of overtime based on time worked and number of working hours
 * in a day.
 */
function calculateOvertime(parsedTime, workingHours) {
    var minutesWorked = parsedTime.hours * 60 + parsedTime.minutes;
    var minutesRequired = workingHours * 60;
    return minutesWorked - minutesRequired;
}
```

Here, the `parseTime` parses the time, returning an object, and `calculateOvertime` calculates the overtime.

**Put it all together**

Putting it together, your actual function does become more compact and more readable because tangental functions are extracted:

```
/**
 * Gets the total minutes of overtime from a tracking table.
 *
 * @param selector A CSS2.1 selector, DOM element or jQuery object pointing to the
 * tracking table.
 */
function getOvertimeFromTable(selector, dailyWorkingHours) {
    var totalMinutesOfOvertime = 0;
    var $dailyTimes = $(selector).find("font:not(:empty)");

    $dailyTimes.each(function () {
        var parsedTime = parseTime($(this).text());
        var minutesOfOvertime = calculateOvertime(parsedTime, dailyWorkingHours);

        totalMinutesOfOvertime += minutesOfOvertime;
    });
}

alert('Overtime so far: ' + getOvertimeFromTable('.links', 8) + ' minutes');
```

**Protecting global, enabling compilation**

Right now we are exposing a variety of variables and functions on the global object.  This means that anyone could call `parseTime` or read a similar function.  It also means a minifier can't rename the function to a shorter name.  Wrapping everything in a closure will be the final step for making sure your output code is more compact and your source needn't be:

```
/**
 * Alerts the number of hours of overtime you have accumulated so far in this pay cycle,
 * assuming a standard 8-hour day.
 */
(function () {
    /* Your code here */
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you only need to pass parameters to `each` if you need the index.

```
$.each(elementsToParse, function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
```

Also, a more elegant way than `substr` is just using `split`. You can `trim` the text before that.

```
var text = $.trim( $(this).text() ).split(':'),
    hours = parseInt( text[0], 10 ),
    minutes = parseInt( text[1], 10 );
```

Don't forget the second parameter of `parseInt` :-)

Comment: How could I forget the second parseInt argument!

Comment: Use `+x` instead of `parseInt(x,10)`. It is [faster](http://jsperf.com/str2intbench/4), shorter and doesn't lose any conveyed meaning.

Comment: Is it more readable, though? (rhetorical question)

Comment: If you're not a js regular, it might not be very explicit, not to say plain obscure. But hey, learn the good parts, right?

Comment: Yes +x is faster, but be careful as it will not have the same results as parseInt(x, 10) if x is not a number.  If x = '10px', parseInt(x, 10) will return 10 where +x will return NaN.

Answer (score 0):

As Inkbug mentions, you could run `each()` straight on the query. `split()` is definitely an elegant means to retrieve minutes and hours. For style reasons, you probably should have 1 `var` inside the the `each()` function. You could split up `480` into `60 * 8`, this makes it clear you are supposed to work 8 hours a day. Finally, if you put the code inside a self executing function, you will not mess up the global namespace, and you can then store the code as a bookmarklet.

This should work:

```
void((function () {
    var totalMinutes = 0;
    $(".link").find("font:not(:empty)").each(function () {
        var time = $(this).text().split(":"),
            hours = +time[0],
            minutes = +time[1],
            overtime = ((hours * 60) + minutes) - (8 * 60);

        totalMinutes += overtime;
    });

    alert('Overtime so far: ' + totalMinutes + ' minutes');
})());
```